# Expanding Thumbnails Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Reference: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails

Ive been using the Twitter Bootstrap, but I can't get the thumbnails to expand to their fullsize image when clicking on them. Do I have to manually implement this using jQuery or does boostrap support this in their JS library?

If I do have to use jQuery can someone point me to where this might be mentioned in their documentation?

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have to manually implement this functionality.

There are a lot of jQuery plugins available for this. I like [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net) and [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone).

This link may help you:
[15 Stunning jQuery Lightbox Plug-ins for Your Upcoming Designs](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/03/29/15-stunning-jquery-lightbox-plug-ins-for-your-upcoming-designs/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Bootstrap.

Like this:

```
    <a href="images/content/dummy-image.jpg" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/content/dummy-image.jpg " alt='Dummy Image' /></a>
```

I set the viewport scale and make sure your Bootstrap JS and CSS links are used too:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because I needed the same thing and the existing answer(s) were not satisfying: there is a nice way with bootstrap alone. I have this function:

```
function image(id, img, text) {
        return text + "<div id='" + id + "' class='modal fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog'>" 
             + "<div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-body'>"
             + "<img src='" + img + "' class='img-responsive'></div></div></div></div>"
             + "<div class='col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-right'><a class='thumbnail' href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#" + id + "'>"
             + "<img src='" + img + "'/></a></div>"
    }
```

This yields HTML like this:

```
<div id="tea-live" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="images/tea-live.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 text-right">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tea-live">
        <img src="images/tea-live.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

this creates a fading in model box on the same page.